# Custom Control ASP.Net - Unordered List with Link inside LI's Control

Tags: asp.net, controls

I need to create a custom control that spits out the the following html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="test.html">link button</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="test.html">link button</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need the links to be LinkButtons and output inside the li elements.

What is the best way of going about building this control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using built-in DataBound Controls like [ListView](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx) Or [Repeater](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/) controls.

You can add LinkButton within the li tags.

Other resources:
http://www.asp.net/aspnet-35/videos/the-listview-control